# Java enum class with a twist

Tags: java, json, serialization, enums, deserialization

I have to model an object which is essentially an enum representing a game level:

```
public enum GameLevel {
    EASY(0, 3, 30),
    NORMAL(1, 4, 40),
    HARD(2, 5, 50);

    private int levelNum;
    private int size;
    private int score;

    private GameLevel(int levelNum, int size, int score) {
        this.levelNum = levelNum;
        this.size = size;
        this.score = score;
    }

    public int getLevelNum() {
        return levelNum;
    }

    public int getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    public int getScore() {
        return score;
    }
}
```

Now my problem is that this enum exists both on my server and on my client (shared library jar).
I'm serializing it with the full content:

```
level { "levelNum":0, "size":3, "score":30 }
```

I have no problem deserializing it back again to an GameLevel enum object.
But, I would like to be able to change it on the server level (e.g: easy size = 6 instead of 3)
and serialize it in the same way but on the client end to be able to deserialize these new values (without changing the object on the client of course, only the server is updated).

I doesn't look like an enum is the right choice for that, but when looking at my code everything is treated in an "enum" like way.

Comment: Just provide setters for the properties.

Comment: Sorry, fixed the normal. And providing setters to an enum sounds hacky doesn't it?

Comment: "I[t] doesn't look like an enum is the right choice for that" <-- Indeed it isn't. Enum instances are `static final`, they have one and only one life over the existence of the JVM. You should look into using something else here ;)

Comment: Question: how do you {de,}serialize this to begin with?

Comment: @fge any ideas how to achieve that in an enum style? (that it, the user of this class should not provide the actual values as they are constants per each level: easy, normal, hard)

Comment: @fge Using custom deserializer of jackson, I'm reading all the values and basically only care about the levelNum one, seems as by adding setters it will solve the issue but it still sounds hacky.

Comment: Make a POJO and have the values final.  Once the `GameLevel` is constructed (ie. deserialized) the values cannot be changed.

Comment: Hmm, using Jackson? Have you considered using `@JsonTypeInfo` and `@JsonSubType`?

Comment: I fail to see the connection to my problem (as there is not polimorphism and inheritance here)? can you please explain?